# Библиотека Deoldify на Windows VPS

Tags: python, сервер, бот, библиотеки

Я новичок в программировании. Нашёл библиотеку Deoldify для Python для колоризации черно-белых фото, но как я понял для её работы нужна хорошая видеокарта. А как тогда запустить на Windows VPS? Хочу создать чат-бот с колоризацией. Или может есть другие бесплатные альтернативы?

Обновлено
Вот мой код

```py
    from PIL import Image
    
    from deoldify import device
    from deoldify.device_id import DeviceId
    
    device.set(device=DeviceId.CPU)
    
    import torch
    
    import fastai
    from deoldify.visualize import *
    
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
    
    # если версия python >= 3.10 необходимо отдельно переназначить модуль 
    Sized 
    import collections
    
    collections.Sized = collections.abc.Sized
    # работаю в соседней папке, импортирую папку DeOldify
    import sys
    
    sys.path.append('./DeOldify')
    
    image_path = '64e20e4c429dba7b67806b5b564a9fa1.jpg'
    
    colorizer = get_image_colorizer(artistic=True)
    
    colorizer.plot_transformed_image(image_path, render_factor=35, 
    display_render_factor=True, figsize=(8,8))


И вылетают ошибки

D:\zPython\z1\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/zPython/z1/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\zPython\z1\main.py", line 14, in <module>
from deoldify.visualize import *
File "D:\zPython\z1\venv\lib\site-packages\deoldify\visualize.py", line 1, in <module>
from fastai.core import *
File "D:\zPython\z1\venv\lib\site-packages\fastai\core.py", line 2, in <module>
from .imports.core import *
File "D:\zPython\z1\venv\lib\site-packages\fastai\imports\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .core import *
File "D:\zPython\z1\venv\lib\site-packages\fastai\imports\core.py", line 2, in <module>
import math, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, pandas as pd, random
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Можно воспользоваться облаками типа AWS / Яндекс.Облако и т.д. Про ЯО точно знаю, что при запуске GPU intensive библиотек платишь только за фактически использованные ресурсы. За VPS же придётся платить ежемесячно.

Comment: А есть ли библиотеки по колоризации без использования видеокарт?

Comment: 99% вероятность что нет

Comment: У меня на VPS указано что видеокарта Microsoft Hyper-V. Подойдёт?

Comment: Это не видеокарта, это гипервизор.

Comment: Вот без GPU: https://github.com/ColorfulSoft/DeOldify.NET

Comment: А есть примеры реализации последней через код?

Comment: Я на самом деле зарядился поставить [себе локально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528823/deoldify-как-использовать-локальную-модель), могу сказать, что можно поставить `device.set(device=DeviceId.CPU)`, а **torch** поставить без CUDA, тогда, по идее, должно работать через ЦП. Но… насколько это дольше будет — одному богу известно. На 1080ti фотографии обрабатываются за секунду. В общем, пробуйте локально без CUDA.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня теперь ошибки, я выше вопрос обновил. Пробую подключить matplotlib, но никак...

Comment: `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Установилось, но всё равно не видит

Comment: Здравствуйте. Тогда всё получилось, но теперь пытаюсь провернуть это же на Windows Server 2012 и ошибка при компиляции ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Не найден указанный модуль., хотя при попытке установки opencv выходит сообщение что уже установлено

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2