# Deoldify, как использовать локальную модель?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Вдохновившись [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528798/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-deoldify-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows-vps), поставил себе локально torch и deoldify.
Пришлось повозиться [с установкой](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-for-cuda-12/169447/41?u=dimithras), т.к. привык к коллабам, а не локальному запуску, но работает отлично.

По библиотеке есть их [сайт](https://deoldify.ai/) ссылающийся на [коллаб](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jantic/DeOldify/blob/master/ImageColorizerColab.ipynb), а также github, описывающий [локальный запуск](https://github.com/jantic/DeOldify#pretrained-weights) и ссылающийся на **.ipynb**, которых нет в репозитории, но есть другие. Видимо документация немного устарела.
Не важно, по тем что есть в репозитории код немного отличается, в основном предлагая использовать фотографии на локальном диске, а не url.

В коде есть следующая строчка:

```python
colorizer = get_image_colorizer()
```

В collab она отрабатывает как задумано. Если нет скачанной модели, то ругается. В **jupyter-notebook** всё немного иначе. Даже если по пути `./models` есть модель, функция всё равно скачивает другую в кэш:

```
Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet101-63fe2227.pth" to C:\Users\User/.cache\torch\hub\checkpoints\resnet101-63fe2227.pth
 33%|█████████████████████████▌                                                    | 56.0M/171M [00:09<00:18, 6.34MB/s]
```

При этом, стоит отметить, что при ключе `artistic = False` скачивается модель размером **171M**, хотя по ссылкам на GH *ColorizeStable_gen.pth* весит **853M**, т.е. что он скачивает не совсем понятно. Я скачал все модели и поместил в соответствующую папку в root проекта.

Конечно же, я посмотрел что из себя представляет функция:

```
<function deoldify.visualize.get_image_colorizer(root_folder: pathlib.Path = WindowsPath('.'), render_factor: int = 35, artistic: bool = True) -> deoldify.visualize.ModelImageVisualizer>
```

И попробовал использовать ключ `root_folder` c `from pathlib import Path` используя путь к root проекта, но это не помогает. Каждый раз функция скачивает модель в **.cache**, не создаёт папку **models** в User root и игнорирует содержимое папки проекта…

### Вопрос

Как использовать локально загруженные модели.
Это тем более критично, потому что скачиваемые автоматически явно меньше чем загруженные с GH.

---

Поискал по самому репозиторию упоминание `get_image_colorizer`, естественно нашлись **.ipynb**, а также по пути "*C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py*":

```python
def get_image_colorizer(
    root_folder: Path = Path('./'), render_factor: int = 35, artistic: bool = True
) -> ModelImageVisualizer:
    if artistic:
        return get_artistic_image_colorizer(root_folder=root_folder, render_factor=render_factor)
    else:
        return get_stable_image_colorizer(root_folder=root_folder, render_factor=render_factor)

def get_stable_image_colorizer(
    root_folder: Path = Path('./'),
    weights_name: str = 'ColorizeStable_gen',
    results_dir='result_images',
    render_factor: int = 35
) -> ModelImageVisualizer:
    learn = gen_inference_wide(root_folder=root_folder, weights_name=weights_name)
    filtr = MasterFilter([ColorizerFilter(learn=learn)], render_factor=render_factor)
    vis = ModelImageVisualizer(filtr, results_dir=results_dir)
    return vis
```

Что именно начинает загрузку, и как использовать локальную модель — мне пока не понятно. В **ModelImageVisualizer** нет никаких признаков скачивания модели.
Да, я пока не пробовал запускать дебаг, возможно ответ на поверхности. Если нет, отвечу сам себе.

Comment: @insolor я думал добавить тег `python`, но передумал из-за того, что torch работает с версиями >3.8

Comment: От этого Python не перестает быть Python

Comment: @insolor думаю да